# Is it okay to extend a base view in Django's error pages (HTTP 404 and 500)?

Tags: django, django-templates, custom-error-pages

Django's [views documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view) states that "the default 500 view passes no variables to this template and is rendered with an empty Context to lessen the chance of additional errors," but is it okay to use the [`{% extends %}`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#extends) tag to re-use a base view in the 500 Server Error page (`500.html`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we have a very basic template that we extend our 404 and 500 templates from.  As long as your base template doesn't rely on a custom context, you should be good.